# Opening and Closing Browser

Tags: tosca

I am new to TOSCA (just trying to learn by self-studying - have a trial license).

I was trying to build a simple test case to open and close an application. In it I have used the TBox Window Operation Module to close the Browser but when I run it in scratchbox, I don't get any output. It just opens the browser to the demo app and exits without giving a success or an error message. I want to know why it isn't closing the browser window and giving me a success message.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Here is a ss of the code]

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your testcase looks alright to me. I just tried myself and this should work.
After you've run the test you can always open up the scratchbook again, by clicking the 'scratchbook' button in the ribbon on the 'home' tab in the 'go to' group:
[image: opening the scratchbook]

You should then see the details of your last run. A very common thing that happens to me is that Tosca cannot uniquely identify the window (e.g. because I have two windows with the same title open). The error would look like this:
[image: error message when more than one window is found]

So I'd check if opened the demo webshop more than once.

What is also good to know is, that Tosca will use your standard browser in the 'OpenUrl' module if you have not specified it otherwise, and the 'Window Operation Module' is agnostic to that. You can explicitly specify which browser to use in the 'OpenUrl' module by providing a TestConfiguration Parameter like this:

[image: specifying the testconfiguration parameter for the browser to use]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

just use `CloseBrowser` module which can be found under `Standard Modules`.

`Standard Modules` are the set of modules which are shipped by default along with the installation of any Tosca instance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "close browser" standard module instead of window operation module to close the browser window.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).